# Writing a string to a new .csv in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, csv

I am trying to write a string to a .csv file, but unable to get it to display.
I have managed to do it in VBA, but when writing in VB.net it's not working.

I first create the file and set the headers for each column. After this I am getting information on each required attribute and writing it to a string s. 
All i want to do now is write the string to the .csv file so that each attribute is in the right column under the right header. 
Each time the string s simply needs to be on a new row.

This is what I have so far (I have cut out some bits of code so some syntax may look incorrect). What am i doing wrong or missing?

```
    Sub Main()
     Dim sOutput As String
    ' Create a header for the output file
    sOutput = ("Level,Occurrence Name,Reference Name,Object type, Visibility, Path" & vbLf)

            If Occs.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Occs.Count
            iLevel = 0
            curOcc = Occs.Item(i)
            GetOccurrenceData(curOcc, sOutput, oSel, False, iLevel)
        Next
    End If

    ' Write the output string to a file
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim bWrite As Boolean
    sPath = ("C:\temp\data3.csv")
    bWrite = WriteFile(sPath, sOutput)
End Sub


Sub GetOccurrenceData(curOcc As VPMOccurrence, s As String, sel As Selection, ByVal bParentHidden As Boolean, ByVal iParentLevel As Integer)
'CODE TO GET DATA REMOVED AS IRRELEVANT 

     ' Append the output string with the data for the current occurrence.
    s = (s & curLevel & "," & sName & "," & sRefName & "," & sType & "," & sVisibility & vbLf)

    ' Repeat this data gathering procedure on any children the current occurrence may have.
    Occs = curOcc.Occurrences
    If Occs.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Occs.Count
            GetOccurrenceData(Occs.Item(i), s, sel, bChildrenInheritNoShow, curLevel)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Show the "WriteFile" function.

Comment: There is much room for improvement.  Rather than trying to make one long string, it would be faster to create a List(of String) where each element is a line. `GetOccurrenceData` could be a function returning a line at a time, or just adding to the List.   There are better ways to format the output

Comment: I added example StringBuilder version of your code in my answer below, anything concatenating lots of strings, StringBuilder is way more performant and cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GetOccurrenceData you pass in a string and change it in the method, but you did not pass it in as a ByRef so anything done to the string in the method stays in the method.

Change the header of your method to read

```
Sub GetOccurrenceData(curOcc As VPMOccurrence,ByRef s As String, sel As Selection, ByVal bParentHidden As Boolean, ByVal iParentLevel As Integer)
```

I would however recommend using a StringBuilder to accomplish what you are doing.

Like This:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine("Level,Occurrence Name,Reference Name,Object type, Visibility, Path")

    If Occs.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Occs.Count
            iLevel = 0
            curOcc = Occs.Item(i)
            GetOccurrenceData(curOcc, sb, oSel, False, iLevel)
        Next
    End If

    ' Write the output string to a file
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim bWrite As Boolean
    sPath = ("C:\temp\data3.csv")
    bWrite = WriteFile(sPath, sb.ToString())

End Sub


Sub GetOccurrenceData(curOcc As VPMOccurrence, sb As Text.StringBuilder, sel As Selection, ByVal bParentHidden As Boolean, ByVal iParentLevel As Integer)
    'CODE TO GET DATA REMOVED AS IRRELEVANT 

    ' Append the output string with the data for the current occurrence.
    sb.Append(curLevel).Append(",").Append(sName).Append(",").Append(sRefName).Append(",").Append(sType).Append(",").AppendLine(sVisibility)

    ' Repeat this data gathering procedure on any children the current occurrence may have.
    Occs = curOcc.Occurrences
    If Occs.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Occs.Count
            GetOccurrenceData(Occs.Item(i), sb, sel, bChildrenInheritNoShow, curLevel)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, I've spent almost all day trying to work this out and all I had to do is add "ByRef" to make it all magically work. Thanks!

Comment: The reason this is necessary is that string is treated as a value type and is copied in to the method with a default ByVal. ByRef tells the compiler that you are planing on changing the string and it should reflect back on the calling method, in essence you pass the memory location of the string verses a copy.